# Visual block insert into multiple areas with no text with virtualedit=all

Tags: visual-mode, virtualedit

When I do a visual block insert with `virtualedit=all` I want to insert into all selected lines regardless of what text is already in those lines. Instead the behavior I get is that the line where I begin the visual block is always inserted into and the other highlighted lines are inserted into only if they already contain text in the selected column or the immediately preceding column.

For example, with `_` as the cursor, and the following text that contains no trailing spaces (the cursor is outside the text):

```
abc  _
abcd
abcde
ab
```

if I begin a visual block where the cursor is and continue down to the last column, then block insert foo, and then press escape I end up with this:

```
abc _foo
abcd
abcdefoo
ab
```

Instead, I want this:

```
abc _foo
abcd foo
abcdefoo
ab   foo
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to the behaviour of blockwise operators. In this particular example, you need to append the text. That is, with the visual block selection, here marked with `_`,

```
abc  _
abcd _
abcde_
ab   _
```

you can type `Afoo<esc>` to get the desired output, i.e.

```
abc _foo
abcd foo
abcdefoo
ab   foo
```

With visual block insert, see `:h v_b_I`, you will only insert text if the line extends into the block. However, with visual block append, see `:h v_b_A`, you will append to every line, even if the lines do not extend into the block. In the latter case, whitespace will be added as expected.

For more information, see `:h blockwise-operators`.

Comment: I realise that i should explain why. However, i did not have the time to find out. I will update if and when i find out :-)

Comment: This asymmetry between insert and append does seem really quirky. If there's a reason I should expect this that would be useful to know. Thanks!

Comment: That's how it is. See `:h blockwise-operators` (`v_b_I`, `v_b_A` follows).

Comment: The reason for that is explained in the [help](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/visual.txt#L331-L333)